# How to fix the typeerror in react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

my code is like below,

```
itemDetails: async (parent, args, { dataSources: { someAPI } }) => {
  const source = get(parent, 'source');
  const id = get(parent, 'id');
  if (id) {
      let output;
      if (source === 'source1') {
          const data = await someAPI.getItem(id);
          output = {
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
          }
      }
      if (source === 'source2') {
          const data = await someAPI.getItem(id);
          output = {
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
          } 
      }
      if (output) {
          return {
              id: output.id,
              name: output.name,
          }
      } else {
          return {};
      }
  } else {
      return {};
  }
```

},

the above code works but if i return the output within each if condition like below code it throws error that

the type id? : any, name?: any cannot be assigned to id? undefined , name?: undefined type

```
itemDetails: async (parent, args, { dataSources: { someAPI } }) => {
  const source = get(parent, 'source');
  const id = get(parent, 'id');
  if (id) {
      if (source === 'source1') {
          const data = await someAPI.getItem(id);
          return { //returning here
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
          }
      }
      if (source === 'source2') {
          const data = await someAPI.getItem(id);
          return { //returning here
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
          } 
      }
        
  } else { //no id 
      return {};
  }
```

},

not sure what the problem is. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Which line does the error occur?

Comment: in first line under itemDetails i see a red line in my IDE.

Comment: if i replace the another if (source === 'source2') with else { it works